# How to do seamless handover of numpy.memmap? Used for .wav files in Python

Tags: python, numpy, split, wav

I am currently checking some ways to process biiiiiig .wav files in python. These files can be >2gb. I found numpy.memmap and I like the concept and it should also provide some boost in the later signal processing, but my problem is, that it can only handle file sizes of <2gb as stated here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

So I am currently checking, if there is a trick to increase this. Or how to split the file to several memmap files, which are later on used for the processing. But for this, I will need some kind of seamless handover to iterate through all parts of the original memmap file.

How would you do that? I googled for a while but couldn't find anything useful.

Best regards,

Andreas

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe that only applies is you're using python 2.4 or earlier.  (Note the "prior to Python 2.5" note.) I've certainly memmapped >10GB arrays with numpy.  However, you'll likely find that you're better off working with chunks of the file in memory, regardless.